# Limits of integral ratio: which theorems to use?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I "guessed" the limit  $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty} \frac{\int_{a}^{b} f(x,y)\cdot g(x,y)^ndy}{\int_{a}^{b} h(x,y)\cdot g(x,y)^ndy}=\frac{f(x,a)}{h(x,a)}.$$ where $f,h>0$ and $f,g,h\in C^1([a,b]^2)$ and **more importantly**:  $ 0<g<1$ and $g$ is strictly decreasing in $y$.

The intuition is since for $a<y$, $g(x,y)/g(x,a)<1$, so $g(x,y)^n$ converges to zero "faster" than $g(x,a)^n$ but I'm ashamed to confess I do not know how to establish this formally.

The dominated convergence theorem (if it applies) would allow me to place the limit inside the integral but since each integral is going to zero, I would need something like L'Hospital rule.

Is there any theorem(s) that handles cases like this? I will be dealing with many more similar examples in the future.